# How do I combine lowerCamelCase with all-caps abbreviations? (with style)

Tags: python, coding-style, naming-conventions, camelcasing

Let's assume OSCClient is a class and I want instances of a class to begin with a lower case letter:

```
oSCClient = OSCClient() # ew!
```

edit: I asked this question because of [pep 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) which says: "When using abbreviations in CapWords, capitalize all the letters of the abbreviation.  Thus HTTPServerError is better than HttpServerError."

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176950/acronyms-in-camel-back

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström - No, the question you are referring to as a duplicate is concerning the use of abbreviations in (Java) class names, not instances.

Comment: Deleted tag, deleted comment, now "closed as not constructive"? Wow. Did I step on someones foot or something?

Comment: I deleted my answer because i answered when the question wasn't about Python, but then suddenly it's about Python and i'm getting downvoted. I deleted the tag, but realized it's better to delete my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use

```
oscClient = OSCClient() # yey
```

Comment: Why didn't I come up with this? Now I feel dull.