# Camel case name for class with "IPv4"

Tags: java, naming-conventions, camelcasing

I have class named `Ipv4Address`. What would be idiomatic camel case name for it? By idiomatic I mean meeting [Google Java Style](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html) and meeting Checkstyle [AbbreviationAsWordInName](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_naming.html#AbbreviationAsWordInName) check.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176950/acronyms-in-camel-back) does not answer my question - I'm asking here specifically about what to do with letter "v" that is already lowercase in acronym.

`Ipv` may suggest that there's word "ipv" or acronym "IPV". But actual acronym is "IPv", wich is made of two words: "IP" and "version"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Acronyms in Camel Back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176950/acronyms-in-camel-back)

Comment: Have you considered creating separate packages for each version rather including the version in the class name?  Also a possible duplicate of [this Programmers Stack Exchange article](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/100601/java-class-version-specific-naming-conventions).

Comment: Not an answer to your question but most SDKs in the Java world call classes around IP addresses `InetAddress` or `Inet4Address`. The Java SDK and Google Guava libraries do so.

Comment: What's wrong with `Ipv4Address`? It looks OK to me.

Comment: @MirMasej it suggests that there's word "ipv" or acronym "IPV". But actual acronym is "IPv", wich is made of two words: "IP" and "version".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, according to the first site:

> 1. Convert the phrase to plain ASCII and remove any apostrophes. For example, "Müller's algorithm" might become "Muellers algorithm"
> 2. Divide this result into words, splitting on spaces and any remaining punctuation (typically hyphens).
>
>    Recommended: if any word already has a conventional camel-case appearance in common usage, split this into its constituent parts (e.g., "AdWords" becomes "ad words"). Note that a word such as "iOS" is not really in camel case per se; it defies any convention, so this recommendation does not apply.
> 3. Now lowercase everything (including acronyms), then uppercase only the first character of:
>
>    ... each word, to yield upper camel case, or
>
>    ... each word except the first, to yield lower camel case
> 4. Finally, join all the words into a single identifier.

So:

1. IPv4 Address
2. IPv 4 Address
3. ipv 4 address

   Ipv 4 Address
4. `Ipv4Address`

An example they give that includes `IPv`:

"supports IPv6 on iOS?" -> `supportsIpv6OnIos`

So, it appears that Google does not care that the "v" stands for "version", and as such they treat it as part of a single word, "IPv".

If you are dead-set on making it clear that "v" is "version," you could probably get away with `IpVersion4Address`, though I like the look of `Ipv4Address` better.